# Include Mule Error in custom object, then redirect to O/JMS endpoint

Tags: jms, mule

We have implemented a global exception strategy as part of our Mule flow which redirects the payload object to a JMS outbound endpoint - the endpoint receives the object as a payload but we would also like to include exception information in the payload object itself so that the receiving thread can consume it. So for example the following block works fine but how do I intercept the exception and update the payload with exception summary and stack information?

```
catch-exception-strategy name="globalCatchStrategy"
set-payload value="Error : #[exception.summaryMessage]"/
jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="ActiveMQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="${jms.outbound.queue}"
catch-exception-strategy
```

NOTE - I had to remove the open and close XML braces for it to render in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to resolve this issue in the following manner - we send a serializable DTO as a payload in the JMS message which gets returned back if there is an exception within the flow - so I added the exception attributes to the payload object and attached a transformer before the JMS outbound endpoint above - so now the flow looks like this

```
catch-exception-strategy name="globalCatchStrategy"
custom-transformer class="MyTransformerClass" doc:name="Exception Extractor"
jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="ActiveMQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="${jms.outbound.queue}"
catch-exception-strategy
```

And in the MyTransformerClass instance get the payload as such

```
ExceptionPayload exceptionPayload = message.getExceptionPayload();
```